# Need to move serilog configuration as a extension on ,net 6 web api builder

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have below configuration for serilog now which I want to move as a Extension method,

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => _ = builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()
    ? lc.WriteTo.Console()
    : lc.WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage());
```

When I tried to write below in a separate class library, I am not able to find `WebApplicationBuilder`  reference,

```
public static void ConfigureSerilog(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
    }
```

> The type or namespace name 'WebApplicationBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Which type of project you are adding your extension. In the same .Net6 WebApi project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular class library targets `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`.In order to use [asp.net core in your class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Add

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

to your class library .csproj and then add

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
```

which contains `WebApplicationBuilder`